# How to extract correctly local variables from Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, geolocation

Actually i have this code :

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  var lat = crd.latitude;
  var lon = crd.longitude;
  var acc = crd.accuracy;
  console.log("latitude is ", lat);

  var mydata = {latitude:lat, longitude:lon, accuracy:acc};
  return mydata;
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

I have a lot of doubts about the scope management. How can i get the variables lat, lon and acc out of the function? with return doesn't work... I know that if i declare the variable without the var this will work but I've read that it is a bad practice. I want to extract those three variables for use it with another application like OpenStreetMap...  or OpenWeather.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is probably the most-commonly-asked Javascript question there is.  Your results are coming asynchronously.  You cannot use them synchronously.  You must use them IN the callback itself or call some other function from the callback and pass them to that other function.  Those are your TWO choices.  Also, there are tons of other answers ans articles about handling asynchronous responses.

Comment: I am sorry but question is not clear to me. What is the issue you are facing when you say with return it doesn't work?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, sorry by repeat the question.. And thank you very much for your help, i will research more about it... That callback confuses me.

Comment: @AshutoshUpadhyay Basically was like.. how to pass a local variable from a function to another function or to the global scope without declare the variable as global...  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a very common issue with handling async data in JavaScript.

The trick here is to create a named function and bind the context you want to update when the callback occurs :)

Here is an example of an observer that will automatically update when the property changes when the success, error or any other change occurs.

**HTML**

```
<div id="geolocation">
   <div class="button default"></div>
   <div class="button success">
     <latitude></latitude>
     <longitude></longitude>
     <accuracy></accuracy>
   </div>
   <div class="button error"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var success = function(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  this.default = "latitude is " + crd.latitude;

  var mydata = {
    latitude: crd.latitude,
    longitude: crd.longitude,
    accuracy: crd.accuracy
  };

  this.data = mydata;

}.bind(this);
```

Here is the full working example: http://jsbin.com/giquhayepe/edit?html,js,output

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you help me a lot, i will research more about that too to understand completely.